# When should I put the font abbr when set main font in latex

Tags: fonts

I fount the latex template file sometimes define the fonts in sty file like this:

```
\setCJKmainfont[
BoldFont=AdobeHeitiStd-Regular.otf,
ItalicFont=AdobeKaitiStd-Regular.otf,
SmallCapsFont=AdobeHeitiStd-Regular.otf
]{AdobeSongStd-Light.otf}
```

sometimes define the main fonts like this:

```
\setCJKmainfont[
BoldFont=AdobeHeitiStd-Regular,
ItalicFont=AdobeKaitiStd-Regular,
SmallCapsFont=AdobeHeitiStd-Regular
]{AdobeSongStd-Light}
```

When should we put the font format abbr? Which one is preferred? Is there any more compatible way to define the main font?

Comment: According to the [`fontspec` manual (Part II, section 2.2 "By file name")](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), using the first variant you make absolutely clear to `fontspec` (which is used here under the hood) that what mean a font file name with what you. In the second variant, this is not so clear and the manual suggests, that you add the option `Extension = .otf` to the list.

Comment: The truth is the first style could not work(tell me could not fond the font), the second works. I am confusing with this situation, the fisrt style is more clear than the seconds tyle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose whichever method is suitable.

[image: font spec]

Use `Path=` for non-installed fonts.

Use `Extension=.otf,` to save typing if all files are otf.

The asterisk (`*`) typing shortcut will be replaced by whatever is between the braces (`{}`).

On Windows, system fonts must be "Install for all users".

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[%
Path=C:/Users/.../.../fonts/x/, %masked
%Extension=.otf,
UprightFont=*,
BoldFont=FreeMonoBold.otf,
ItalicFont=Asavari.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.otf,
UprightFeatures={Scale=3,Color=brown},
BoldFeatures={Scale=2},
ItalicFeatures={Color=red},
BoldItalicFeatures={Scale=0.8},
]{bkai00m0.TTF}

\begin{document}

蟬

{\itshape italic text}

{\bfseries bold text}

{\bfseries\itshape bold italic text}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 For the choice of the Chinese character.